# Reward points is not updating in customer account in opencart website

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using opencart 2.0 version. When customer buy any product which has rewards

point that are not updating in "View rewards point" option under "My account".

and show "You do not have any reward points!".

One thing I know that this rewards came from oc_customer_reward table but this

table is not updating when customer place order.

Thanks..!

Comment: If the table is not updating, it means that the query is not working. Go through the flow of your code.

Comment: But its build in feature of opencart. so I want to know in which script it going to update customer_reward table

Comment: You have to go through the controller in order to see this bro.

Comment: Ok but as per my little knowledge of opencart coding every database activity is comes under model not controller.

Comment: In controller, you will get to know the appropriate model. :)

Comment: Yes.But It not updating from beginning time of installation.

Comment: Hello, I got solution of my question.It is under Opencart admin panel.No needs to update any table.

Comment: That's good. Reward points were not enabled?

Comment: It enabled. By going sales->orders we can add rewards of particular order id.

Comment: Awesome. Good effort. (Y)